# Auto format in eclipse from commit dialog

Tags: eclipse

is there a possibility to automatically format the code and organize imports for all staged files. I used to work with Idea IDE and there you can check a box right before you commit your code.

I am only committing with eclipse so I do not want every single file changed.

Thanks and Best Regards
Matt

Comment: Do format on save via so-called _Save Actions_: _Project > Properties: Java Editor > Save Actions_.

Comment: As I wrote I am not changing the files in eclipse and do not want to save every single file again.

Comment: This workflow is not supported. As already told, in Eclipse formatting can be done automatically on save, so there is no need to mess committing with formatting, as IDEA does.

Comment: Is there an alternative then to centralize code formatting something like black code formatter for python but for java? Then I could do this with a pre-commit hook.

Comment: You can apply formatting and clean-ups to one or more files, folders or projects at once. If the others use Eclipse and _Save Actions_, only the files changed by you will be changed then.